# How many ordered triples $(a, b, c)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math

How many ordered triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers exist with the property
that $abc = 500$?

Breaking it up, $500 = 2^2\cdot5^3$

$abc = 2^2 \cdot 5^3 = 2\cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$

But how can I use this?

Comment: It might help you to list down the divisors instead (or on top) of the prime factorization.

Comment: Since $(a,b,c)$ is ordered, you need to pick which prime factors go in which slots. The first slot can have $x\in[0,5]$ factors. The second slot can have $y=5-x$ factors, etc.

Comment: @IanColey, I dont seem to understand. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: You know that $abc$ has to contain precisely those prime factors $2,2,5,5,5$. You just need to pick how to arrange them. I suppose my answer isn't quite right, as it might overcount some possibilities. As barak says, you should count the divisors as well as the prime factors.

Comment: How do I get the divisors?

Comment: There are $3$ kids, $A$, $B$, and $C$. I have $2$ identical apples, and $3$ identical oranges. I want to distribute the apples and oranges among the $3$ kids. If there are $m$ ways to distribute the apples, and $n$ ways to distribute the oranges, then there are $mn$ ways to do the fruit-giving.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I am aware of the counting principle. But how would that help here?

Comment: The numbers are very small, so one can list explicitly the ways to distribute the apples, the ways to distribute the oranges, by dividing into cases. But for something interesting, which will work with much larger numbers, I recommend the Wikipedia article Stars and Bars.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the answer is supposed to be $60$.

Comment: Stars and Bars shows there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to distribute the apples, and $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to do the oranges. The product is $60$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I read the article. But how woudl that apply here? We dont know the sum?

Comment: Yes, we know the sum. For the apples (that is, the $2$'s) we want to solve $x+y+z=2$. For the oranges we want to solve $s+t+u=3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I dont mean Apples and Oranges, I mean the actual problem? Are you hinting something....?

Comment: I am not hinting, I am giving the solution. The apples are $2$'s and the oranges are $5$'s.

Comment: FWIW, Murray S. Klamkin considered the condition that the three numbers be consecutive positive integers, with one of them prime, another the product of two primes, and the other the product of three primes. Here is the link to an article (‘The class of Klamkin triples’, by Krystal Lakeysha Williams) on this: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/13503497.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve a slightly more general problem, the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that $abc=n=2^s5^t$. The solution generalizes nicely to $k$-tuples, and any positive  $n$, given the prime power factorization of $n$.

The answer is the number of ways to distribute the $s$ $2$'s between $a$, $b$, and $c$, times the number of ways to distribute the $t$ $5$'s between $a$, $b$, and $c$.

By Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia) there are $\binom{s+3-1}{3-1}$ ways to distribute the $2$'s, and $\binom{t+3-1}{3-1}$ ways to distribute the $5$'s.

In our particular case we get $\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}$.

**Remark:**  The solution is overkill. For $n=500$, we can count explicitly the ways to distribute the $2$'s, and the ways to distribute the $5$'s. Let's do the $5$'s. They all could go to one person ($3$ ways). Or else they could be distributed evenly ($1$ way). Or $2$ could go to one person, and $1$ to another ($(3)(2)$ ways).  So there are $10$ ways to distribute the $5$'a. A similar but simpler analysis shows there are $6$ ways to distribute the $2$'s.

Comment: I like the rigorous solution more. Nice job!

Comment: I don't know Norwegian but the answer is supossed to be 60 http://abelkonkurransen.no/problems/abel_1314_r2_sol_nb.pdf

Comment: Sure, $\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}=60$.

Comment: Yes I noted that later I was confused by the "total is 10"

Comment: I did not want to show that there are $6$ ways to distribute the two $2$'s, (i) $3$ ways in which somebody gets them all and (ii) $3$ ways in which two get one each. That's because it is basically the same analysis as the distributing the three $5$'s case, but simpler.

Comment: @rlartiga: Thanks for asking, I have added to the remark to make it clear we also need to deal with the $2$'s.